# How to properly update layout with moveable elements in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, position

Today I'm trying to create a layout with a 4 ImageViews and a ListView and update the listview position according to the ImageView position.

An SS to show you what I'm trying to do:

[image]
[image]

As you can see the ListView position gets updated once we pull the "Gray Handle".
Everything works kinda ok, but while moving the handle the graphic isn't smooth but stuttering.

The code I use for this looks like this;

```
btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent me) {
            if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                status = START_DRAGGING;
            }
            if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                status = STOP_DRAGGING;
                Log.i("Drag", "Stopped Dragging");
            } else if (me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
                if (status == START_DRAGGING) {
                    System.out.println("Dragging");

                    GestureImageView image1 = (GestureImageView) findViewById(R.id.image1);
                    GestureImageView image2 = (GestureImageView) findViewById(R.id.image2);

                    ImageView header = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageHeader);

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                    lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                    margin1 = (int) me.getRawY() - 100;
                    if (margin1 < header.getHeight() - btn.getHeight() / 3)
                        margin1 = header.getHeight() - btn.getHeight() / 3;
                    else if (margin1 > layout.getHeight() - 1.5
                            * btn.getHeight() - btn3.getHeight())
                        margin1 = (int) (layout.getHeight() - 1.5
                                * btn.getHeight() - btn3.getHeight());
                    lp.topMargin = margin1;
                    btn.setLayoutParams(lp);

                    if (margin1 >= margin2 - 35) {
                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

                        newlp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
                        margin2 = margin1 + 35;
                        newlp.topMargin = margin2;
                        btn2.setLayoutParams(newlp);

                        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams newlp2 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                        newlp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, btn2.getId());
                        newlp2.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, header.getId());
                        newlp2.bottomMargin = -(15 + margin2);
                        image2.setLayoutParams(newlp2);
                        image2.setAdditionalY(image2.getHeight(),
                                margin2 - 85, image2.getScaledHeight()
                                        - margin2 - 85);
                    }

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp3 = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
                    lp3.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, btn.getId());
                    lp3.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, header.getId());
                    lp3.bottomMargin = -(15 + margin1);
                    image1.setLayoutParams(lp3);
                    image1.setAdditionalY(image1.getHeight(), margin1 - 50,
                            image1.getScaledHeight() - margin1 - 50);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

As you can see I add a listener to the "Gray Handle" and on moving I update Layout rules and calculate the margins. Is there a better way to do this?

Thx in advance for trying to help me.

**EDIT:** 
I forgot to add that the bigger the listView the bigger the stutter and I think it's caused by the listView rebuilding all views while changing its position.

**EDIT2:**
I did some testing, added logs and while moving the listview, all views get rebuilt everytime the listview moves. Is there a way to stop this? Maybe make it rebuild once the user stops moving the images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by optimizing "getView" in my ListView.

For everyone that has problems with listViews:

1. If convertView exists dont create a new view
2. Use ViewHolders
3. Never create a Typeface in getView, create all typefaces on calling the constructor
4. If you fill the List with data from a database create a class where you will be keeping all needed data, instead of calling the DB every new view is created.